# Angular DatePipe with locale usage

Tags: angular

I want to display the date in HTML depending on the set/used locale. For display purposes I want to display it in English or German - depending on the users decision. This means the user select the locale 'de' or 'en'.

The default way to display the date is

```
 <span>{{ data.selDate | date: "mediumDate" }}</span>
```

According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) I have `{{ value_expression | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}`. But this code won't work

```
 <span>{{ data.selDate | date: "mediumDate" :'':"de-DE" }}</span>
 <span>{{ data.selDate | date: "mediumDate" :undefined:"de-DE" }}</span>
```

How to specify it in the DatePipe?

Comment: try <span>{{ data.selDate | date: "mediumDate" :"de-DE" }}</span>

Comment: Won't work either - still displays the date in default locale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the additional locale's

You can try:

component.html

```
<button (click)="switch('en-US')">Eng</button>
<button (click)="switch('de-DE')">Deu</button>

<span>{{ data.selDate | date: 'mediumDate':'': current }}</span>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeEn from '@angular/common/locales/en';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';

registerLocaleData(localeDe);
registerLocaleData(localeEn);
```

component.ts

```
current: string = 'de-De';

switch(new: string): void {
  this.current = new;
}
```

NOTE: make sure `selDate` is a valid date

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-y4cfgp?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: The registration is essential. With Angular 17 I get an exception about the missing language and this isn't even reported to the console :-/ Just out of curiosity: In English I get  for `mediumDate` "Dec 17th, 2023" while for `de` I get no month name (`17.12.2023`) any clues why the name is omitted?

Comment: The difference in date formatting between English ("Dec 17th, 2023") and German ("17.12.2023") that you're observing is due to the structural formatting rules for dates in different locales as defined in the Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR). So it outputs what is commonly used in each locale based of CLDR. https://cldr.unicode.org/

Answer (score 3):

By default, Angular only has locale information for the en-US locale. Any additional locales need to be imported into your application.

E.g.like this for german in your app module file.

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';

registerLocaleData(localeDE);
```

If you have more locales, you might want to look into dynamic loading of the needed locale on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example from stackblitz, not created by me.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  date = new Date();

  constructor(public datePipe: DatePipe) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.datePipe.transform(this.date, 'mediumDate', '', 'ar-AE'))
  }
}
```

html

```
<p>{{ date | date:'longDate':'':'ar-AE' }}</p>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-locale)

Comment: As I've found an answer just a short "feedback". The provided Stackblitz code seems to work. But the Version is Angular 7 - which is not the newest one. With Angular 16 the provided code won't work. You don't get even an error on the console mentioning that some locales are missing - just as a side note. Thx nevertheless for your efforts.